# How to comment out a HTML tag in .Vue 's template

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, visual-studio-code

Recently, I'm start learning Vue and using Vue-Cli. There's a problem that I can not use hot-key(VSCode) to comment out a HTML tag in the . when I use "Ctrl+/" the line I want to comment out turns like this.

```
// <div> comment out this line</div>
```

not like this.

```
<!--<div> comment out this line</div>-->
```

Is there any possibility that I changed some setting in the VSCode to result this situation? Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For single line comment use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>. This will do something like this

```
// <div> comment out this line</div>
```

and for block comment use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>. This will comment lines like this

```
<!-- <div> comment out this line</div>

     <div> comment out this line</div>

     <div> comment out this line</div> -->
```

or

```
/* <div> comment out this line</div>

   <div> comment out this line</div>

   <div> comment out this line</div> */
```

In order to change shortcut key

- **Windows:** File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts.
- **MacOS:** Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts.

and then search for comment like this [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgIn6.png)

Comment: You can mention this as well:
`// <div> comment out this line</div> // prints in browser` and
`//- <div> comment out this line</div> // Doesn't prints in browser`

Answer (score 7):

Like tony19 mentioned, installing the [Vetur](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur) VSCode extension adds Vue language support, which correctly sets up comment toggling in Vue files.

Answer (score 0):

**In the template or HTML section use HTML comments**

**In the script, section use Javascript comments**

// Comment
/* Comment */

**In style section use CSS comments**

/* comment */

Comment: You should add "code" wrapper in stackoverflow. HTML comment ignored.